# The specified library "bootstrap/drupal.ajax" does not exist

Tags: 8, multi-sites, bootstrap-theme

I'm trying to separate a multisite instance in to separate websites. I created two separate instances and moved custom themes and contrib modules in to site specific folders.

When I try to load the site getting following error:
[image]

Site is using custom bootstrap subtheme and same database.

Comment: _and moved custom themes_ did you also move contrib themes? As in the bootstrap theme? The error would suggest not

Comment: Yes. Base theme also moved. But the folder structure is changed. Previously site specific themes were under 'sites' folder. Now it moved under docroot/themes/custom/mycustomtheme and bootstrap theme is at docroot/themes/contrib/bootstrap.

Comment: That'll probably be the problem. Clearing the cache should fix it

Comment: Yup! Cleard cache fixed the issue.